What is happening with my evergreens?
I have some evergreens (emerald green aborvitae) in my backyard that have started getting brown spots which are starting to climb the tree. My neighbors seem to have the same thing happening, except one has gotten to the point where the whole tree is dead.
Can anyone give me ideas on what's going on? Is it a fungal thing? Something else? It's rained recently so I think they're watered enough. And I haven't noticed bugs on them. Thanks in advance for any ideas!




Can we get a closeup picture?

How long has it been since they've been planted?

Ah sorry, just saw these replies. I’ll get a closeup picture posted tomorrow.
It’s been about 8 months since they’ve been planted.

@kevinskio just added a couple closeups
